# How to compile ld with custom linker scripts?

Tags: linux, linker, ld, linker-scripts, linux-from-scratch

i am trying to build a custom version of the linux kernel 3.8 and i want my linker to behave a bit different so i changed its ldscripts.
Specifically I *configure binutils -> make -> **change ldscripts** -> make install*.
However when i try to compile libc using my linker the only thing i see is this :

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.23
  Supported emulations:
   elf32_sparc
   sparclinux
   elf64_sparc
   sun4
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for --shared -z combreloc: shared library, combine & sort relocs */
```

etc

The thing is that i have changed my ldscripts and prepended a tag at the beginning of each script in order to recognize them but my compiler does not seem to care.
However i don't have any other *elf* scripts in my system so the option of searching the wrong *library path* is not actually an option.

Is there something i am missing here?

*Notice that i am cross compiling for sparc*

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom linker script to `ld`:

```
ld -T <path/to/file> ...
```

or to `gcc`:

```
gcc -Wl,-T,<path/tofile> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Default `ld` scripts get compiled into compiler driver (`gcc`) so you should at least rebuild the toolchain.

That's also probably the case that `gcc` will not look at any linker scripts other than built into it, so you'll have to modify them in toolchain (it's probably in spec files somewhere).